# how to draw a circuit diagram with only using nor and not gates?

Tags: nor

I am approaching with double invert, with ~(~Y) but cannot find the way to draw a circuit diagram of Y=A(B+CD).

Any advice would really be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~(X nor Y) is (X or Y)

(~X nor ~Y) is (X and Y)

~(~X) is X

So,

CD = (~C nor ~D)

B+CD = ~(B nor (~C nor ~D))

A(B+CD) = ~A nor ~(~(B nor (~C nor ~D))) = ~A nor (B nor (~C nor ~D))

Comment: I appreciate it. but cannot express with the clear diagram.

Comment: Y=A(B+CD). so do not I have to using invert - invert ?